# How to find whether the page in word document has the combination of specific text?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, interop

I am new to word interop.

I have a document which has below text inserted only at the start of the table.

OAAssistant3|Table|Header|After|N|T ** Do Not Delete This Text **<>{TN} GRA302

On all other pages it has only {TN} inserted.

How can i find whether the page has the occurrences of the text having both 'OAAssistant3' and {TN}?

This text 'OAAssistant3' is a hidden text but {TN} is not a hidden text.

I have used below code to find {TN} 
But i want to search whether page has both OAAssistant3 and {TN}.

How can I do it?

```
    Dim tableNameSearchRange As Word.Range = document.WordDocument.Content

    With tableNameSearchRange
        .TextRetrievalMode.IncludeHiddenText = False
        .TextRetrievalMode.IncludeFieldCodes = False
        .Find.Text = "\{TN*\}?"
        .Find.MatchWildcards = True
        .Find.Forward = True
        .Find.Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop
    End With
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search for a particular text in the word file and Pro-grammatically change it using Word interop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54267591/how-to-search-for-a-particular-text-in-the-word-file-and-pro-grammatically-chang)

Comment: This s a duplicate of a question asked last week. There, a request for more clarification was made - how the document is actually structured is no clearer. Is all the text in a table? All in the same table row? Are the two search terms in the same table cell, if they exist? Always in the first cell of a table? You get the idea... Please use the edit link under the *first* question to make that clearer. Also, the code there can be replaced. Or delete that question and edit this one to provide full information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the TN replaced - your problem description both here and in your other thread is unclear - in VBA you'd do this with code like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "OAAssistant3[!^13\{]@\{TN"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    i = i + 1
    .Start = .End - 2
    .Text = i
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Whether any of the text is formatted as hidden is of no consequence. I'll leave it to you to do the .NET conversion.